# Entity Framework with some table unique and other are different based on client

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am making a middleware project, which have some functionality, which are same for every client. For this I have make many tables, and update migration in every client, issue is, whenever I changed any table on any client based on any condition, I need to update it on another client also.

Let's say I have tables in which User Information, Chatting Modules and Company Information Modules are same and every clients need other information of their customer based on their businesses, so we have to make another tables also. When I changed any table in any client, I have to changed it on other client also. I need a solution where I can make some table unique for every client, and other tables are based on client requirement.

I am using Entity Framework with a code-first approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 1 BaseDBContext for common tables. Then for each client, create their own DBContext such as ClientADBContext, ClientBDBContext.

Client and base context can have same connection string, but you need to manually manage the migration scripts. So better to have 2 databases for 2 contexts.